Does "Declaration Reflects Use" Rule Apply to C++ Reference Variables?
I'm reading some sections of "The C Programming Language" by Kernighan and Ritchie. In the pointers section, the authors state:

"The syntax of the declaration for a variable mimics the syntax of expressions in which the variable might appear."

I believe this principle is similar to the "Declaration Reflects Use" rule often discussed in C and C++ programming.
However, when I started learning about reference variables in C++, I found it difficult to apply this rule. For instance: int& ref = x;
The use of ref doesn't require the & symbol, unlike its declaration.
My questions are:

Is the statement from K&R the same as the "Declaration Reflects Use" rule?

Does this rule apply to C++ reference variables? If so, how?
If it doesn't apply, why might C++ have deviated from this principle for references?



It's not a universal rule, and references obviously deviate from it because the whole point of them is to avoid having to annotate the uses specially.

The & in a reference declaration functions more like a qualifier than "use" syntax. But they chose to use a syntax with a character that can appear in expressions.

K&R is of dubious value these days even for information about C. It's more a historical document than anything. And trying to extend it to apply to C++, which is by now an almost completely different language, is even less helpful.

The whole point of references is that they act exactly as if you had used the name of the variable that they refer to instead when their name is used in an expression. There is not supposed to be any special syntax that needs to be applied first like for pointer (*).
So how could you possibly differentiate a reference variable declaration from an object declaration variable if they also had to look exactly the same according to the rule you are asking about?
So, no, the rule does not apply to references and can't apply if the intended behavior should be possible.
Why exactly a symbol that already has a meaning in expressions (&) was used to denote references instead of e.g. introducing a new keyword or token, you would probably have to ask Bjarne Stroustrup. My guess would be that it was simply convenient to implement and use at the time. Maybe there was also a loose connection with the original meaning of & in expression in that references refer to other objects just like & forms a pointer, aka reference, to an object.

Probably means that Bjarne or someone he knows is familiar with classical languages.  The original meaning of &  (in natural language) was as (a slightly corrupted form of) "and per se" (where "per se" is the latin for "by itself" or "of itself").      For the context of declaring references (essentially, an alias or alternative name for an object), to a linguist, the & makes sense.
